# Electron Desktop APP

Tags: angularjs, desktop-application, electron

i was trying to learn how to develope a Desktop app using Electron.
I found that guide:
http://www.toptal.com/javascript/electron-cross-platform-desktop-apps-easy

but many things are changed ( 'icp' module now is deprecated e.g.)
Now:

Here is my code

app.js

```
    var app = require('app'),
        ipc = require('electron').ipcMain,
        BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

    var mainWindow = null,
        insertWindow = null;

    function createInsertWindow() {
        insertWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
            show: false
        });

        insertWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/windows/insert/insert.html');

        insertWindow.on('closed',function() {
            insertWindow = null;
        });

        insertWindow.show();
    }

    app.on('ready', function() {
        mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 1024,
            height: 768
        });

        mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/windows/main/main.html');
        mainWindow.openDevTools();

        ipc.on('toggle-insert-view', function() {
               if(! insertWindow) {
                        createInsertWindow();
                } else {
                    return ( insertWindow.isVisible() ) ?  insertWindow.hide() :      insertWindow.show();
                }
            });
        });
```

main.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.view.js"></script>


        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Electron Desktop App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>EDA</h1>
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
            <button toggle-insert-view class="mdl-button">
                add
            </button>
        </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

main.view.js
        var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

```
    angular
        .module('Utils', [])
        .directive('toggleInsertView', function() {
            return function(scope, el) {
                el.bind('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    ipcRenderer.send('toggle-insert-view');
                });
            };
        });
```

When the main windows show up i click on button 'Add' &&  nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

You should move `ipc.on('toggle-insert-view', function...)` outside of the `app.on('ready', function...)`